# Play Developer Api, edits.tracks.update not work

Tags: python, android, google-play-developer-api

I have an Android app released on PlayStore.

In general, when I release a new version to the PlayStore, I set the 'user fraction' to 30%.

Then, I will monitor it for a few days and if there are no major problems, I will gradually increase it and deploy it to 100%.

I do this on the PlayConsole Web site.

But I want to do this programmatically.

So I found the API and created a Python code.

```py
args = argparser.parse_args()
user_fraction = args.user_fraction

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('key.json', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher')  
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)
service build('androidpublisher', 'v3', http=http)

# get edit id
edit_request = service.edits().insert(body={}, packageName=package_name)
result = edit_request.execute()
edit_id = result['id']
print('edit id: %s' % edit_id)

result = service.edits().tracks().patch(
  editId=edit_id, 
  packageName=package_name, 
  track="production", 
  body={
    "releases": [
      {
        "versionCodes": [ target_code ],
        "userFraction": 0.4,
        "status": "inProgress"
      }
    ]
  }
).execute()
println(result)
```

When I run this code, it prints below response:

```json
{
  "track": "production", 
  "releases": [
    {
      "versionCodes": [ xxx ], 
      "status": "inProgress", 
      "userFraction": 0.4
    }
  ]
}
```

The userFraction was changed!
But when I open the PlayConsole, the User fraction doesn't change.
It still 30%.

Why the web page is still showing 0.3?
Is this a caching issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause and solution.

I missed the extra function call.

I should call `commit` too!

```py
  result = service.edits().commit(
    editId=edit_id, 
    packageName=package_name, 
  ).execute()
```

After this call, it works fine!